# How to extract complete attribute value from a JSON response

Tags: jmeter

I am getting response like the below format:

```
{"data":{"A":"12345","B":"03453","c":"08/10/2017","status":"INITIATED"},"error":null,"warning":null,"info":null,"validationError":null}
```

I want to fetch and store value of A using Regular. Can someone guide me how can I get this.

Expected Ouptut : `12345`.

Let me know any details required.

Note:

`"data":{"A":"12345","B":"03453","c":"08/10/2017","status":"INITIATED"}`

its enclosed by another {}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Post Processor to your Sampler

1. Regular Expression Extractor with `(\d+)` is the simpliest.

   Reference Name: "A":"(\d+) to get numbers of A key.
2. JSON Extractor with `$.data.A` as JSON   Path expressions

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to parse JSON data is not the best option, since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) you have [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows executing [JsonPath queries](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) against responses which is a way more easy, robust and reliable option.

A JsonPath query to get your `A` attribute value would be as simple as `$..A`

[image: JMeter JSON PAth Extractor]

If you are still looking for a Regular Expression option, you can use something like `"A":"(.+?)"`.

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor]

But be aware that any extra space or line break will ruin your regular expression while JsonPath approach will work.